# Layout package. Loading geometry creates a different result

Tags: geometry

I've just discovered the super interesting `layout` package that enables you to have an actual visual of the parameters of your page.

I use the `geometry` package in my workflow.

Sounded great to cope with my attempts (struggles :)  to adjust my own page geometry.

However, in my very minimal example, once `geometry` is loaded, I get a very different result whether geometry is loaded or not.

What have I missed ?

**Without `geometry`**

[image]

**With `geometry`**

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{layout}

%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{left=20.00mm, textwidth=140mm,marginparsep=4.2mm, marginparwidth=36.0mm}%

\begin{document}

\layout

\end{document}
```

Comment: geometry changes the values, use the option `pass` if you don't want this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. But if I uncomment the `\geometry{...}` in my MWE, nothing changes.

Comment: Shouldn't layout then be loaded after using geometry?

Comment: @daleif I had the same intuition as you but no effect. the pass option to geometry remove the following geometry.

Comment: You should of course not still use the pass option if you're using the other features of geometry. The pass option is there to keep geometry from changing the original values, but can still pass them on to the pdf.

Comment: @daleif thank you for this final explanation !

Comment: Take a look at the `layouts` package which provides means of showing the default layout. the current layout, and what other layouts would look like.